# Xorg using all my memory RAM?

Tags: xorg, ram, swap, memory-usage, memory-leak

I am having some memory problems that I don't know how to explain, and I don't have the knowledge to investigate it properly. Hope someone can guide me through it.

Since yesterday my notebook (Ubuntu 20.04) is running out of RAM after some time of use. The only software running during these incidents were: Firefox, 2 instances of Discord, VisualCodeStudio and TelegramDesktop.

What bugs me is that when everything starts to get really slow (swap memory starts being used) I immediately close all my software, hoping that the allocated memory would be freed, but even after that all my 16GB of RAM keeps allocated.

[image]

This makes me think that the memory is being used by the Xorg. Can it be concluded?
Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Here are my lshw output:

```
pcpj-predator               
    description: Notebook
    product: Predator PH315-52 (0000000000000000)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.11
    serial: NHQ63AL002040278109501
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0.1 dmi-3.0.1 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=notebook family=Predator Helios 300 sku=0000000000000000 uuid=7971E58C-E699-EA4C-BFD2-99503FD6C9D2
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Covini_CFS
       vendor: CFL
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.11
       serial: NBQ5411004041004059501
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.11
          date: 03/25/2020
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 4018MHz
          capacity: 4500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=6 enabledcores=6 threads=12
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 384KiB
             capacity: 384KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 1536KiB
             capacity: 1536KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 12MiB
             capacity: 12MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
             product: SF4642G8CK8IEHLSBG
             vendor: AMD
             physical id: 0
             serial: 055ED6D2
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:a0000000-b40fffff ioport:b4100000(size=1048576)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: TU106M [GeForce RTX 2060 Mobile]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:152 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b2000000-b207ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: TU106 High Definition Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:b4000000-b4003fff
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi pciexpress pm xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:141 memory:b4100000-b413ffff memory:b4140000-b414ffff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.11.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 5.11
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 5.11.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 5.11
                   capabilities: usb-3.10
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
           *-serial
                description: Serial bus controller
                product: TU106 USB Type-C UCSI Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.3
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: msi pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvidia-gpu latency=0
                resources: irq:125 memory:b4004000-b4004fff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:150 memory:b5000000-b5ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:b4510000-b4517fff
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:b4524000-b4524fff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:b4525000-b4525fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:b4500000-b450ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Mouse
                   product: USB Gaming Mouse
                   vendor: E-Signal
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 1.30
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: HD User Facing
                   vendor: SunplusIT Inc
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.11.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.11
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:b4520000-b4521fff memory:b4526000-b4526fff
        *-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlp0s20f3
             version: 10
             serial: cc:d9:ac:8f:60:e7
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-38-generic firmware=46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- ip=192.168.100.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: irq:16 memory:b4518000-b451bfff
        *-serial:0
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:8f800000-8f800fff
        *-serial:1
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:8f801000-8f801fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:143 memory:b4529000-b4529fff
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:b4522000-b4523fff memory:b452d000-b452d0ff ioport:5080(size=8) ioport:5088(size=4) ioport:5060(size=32) memory:b452c000-b452c7ff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:b4400000-b44fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:b4400000-b4403fff
              *-nvme0
                   description: NVMe device
                   product: SAMSUNG MZVLB256HBHQ-00007
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: /dev/nvme0
                   version: EXH7202Q
                   serial: S4GHNF0MC02531
                   configuration: nqn=nqn.2014.08.org.nvmexpress:144d144dS4GHNF0MC02531      SAMSUNG MZVLB256HBHQ-00007 state=live
                 *-namespace
                      description: NVMe namespace
                      physical id: 1
                      logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
                      size: 238GiB (256GB)
                      capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                      configuration: guid=7decc6c7-3b0e-4cd0-9008-614d955451d8 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
                    *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                         description: Windows FAT volume
                         vendor: mkfs.fat
                         physical id: 1
                         version: FAT32
                         serial: 6991-fa2b
                         size: 474MiB
                         capacity: 475MiB
                         capabilities: boot fat initialized
                         configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
                    *-volume:1
                         description: EXT4 volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 2
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
                         logical name: /
                         version: 1.0
                         serial: e327cf7b-33b8-42e0-b5f8-aa9da41e7482
                         size: 223GiB
                         capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                         configuration: created=2021-09-13 09:37:18 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2021-10-22 09:35:55 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2021-10-22 09:35:55 state=mounted
                    *-volume:2
                         description: Linux swap volume
                         vendor: Linux
                         physical id: 3
                         logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p3
                         version: 1
                         serial: a9599deb-1fbe-45d7-98bd-db34f8ac974d
                         size: 14GiB
                         capacity: 14GiB
                         capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                         configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #13
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:b4300000-b43fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                logical name: enp7s0
                version: 10
                serial: 7c:8a:e1:dc:50:7e
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=5.11.0-38-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:16 memory:b4300000-b433ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:151 memory:b451c000-b451ffff memory:b4200000-b42fffff
        *-serial:2
             description: SMBus
             product: Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 10
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:b452a000-b452a0ff ioport:5040(size=32)
        *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 10
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe010000-fe010fff
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0303
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-scsi
          physical id: a
          logical name: scsi4
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD10SPZX-21Z
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1A02
             serial: WD-WX22A70R4VV2
             size: 931GiB (1TB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=98a5899a-2b39-dd4c-9cc5-63ce453cf021 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /home/pcpj/1TBHD
                version: 3.1
                serial: 6844-9b43
                size: 927GiB
                capacity: 927GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2021-03-18 14:32:05 filesystem=ntfs mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 name=DataStorage state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                version: 3.1
                serial: 1232-80ee
                size: 4570MiB
                capacity: 4579MiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2020-09-29 14:44:35 filesystem=ntfs label=WINDRIVER name=Basic data partition state=clean
```

Comment: Strange !!! Have you tried booting into normal desktop environment like Ubuntu , Ubuntu on Wayland , Kde or other , Have you tried using lightdm ? Does the problem still exists with different desktop and display manager ?

Comment: No I haven't tried anything like that. I am using this ubuntu installation for months without any problem, this started this week. The only "odd" thing I did was to install the DroidCam client, to use my phone as a webcam. I don't even know for sure if it is the Xorg that is using all my RAM. Can I be sure about it?

Comment: Umm..... It's not Xorg but Gnome display manager which is taking that RAM , That is why I suggested to download lightdm , To see if other display managers also take the same Ram or not. Also are you using alot of extensions or using some really high quality of wallpapers and configurations , That can be a common cause

Comment: The only Gnome extension I am using is the "Desktop Icons" (
    https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons).
But it wouldn't explain why the problem just started this week.
How can I install the lightdm? Is there a chance that it will mess with my nvidia drivers?

Comment: Add your detailed system specs: `sudo lshw`.

Comment: @vanadium Done!

Comment: Your titles the issue "RAM", but Xorg takes only 14Mb of RAM (see RES-idential memory column).

Comment: Also having this same issue.